# Javascript Element Selector in Loops

Tags: javascript, html

Hi let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <table>
                <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
                <tr><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
            </table>
        </li>
        <li>
            <table>
                <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
                <tr><td>9</td><td>10</td></tr>
                <tr><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
            </table>
        </li>
        <li>
            <table>
                <tr><td>13</td><td>14</td></tr>
                <tr><td>15</td><td>16</td></tr>
                <tr><td>17</td><td>18</td></tr>
            </table>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now I want to add some classes to only visible tds with Javascript, no jQuery. The thing is that I don't know the amount of tds of each tr. So it could be 2 tds for each tr or 3, but it's always the same amount and some of these tds could be hidden.

JS Code:

```
var li = document.querySelectorAll(".test > ul > li");
var tr = document.querySelectorAll(".test > ul > li tbody tr");

for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    if(i == 1 || i == 2) {
        for(var j = 0; j < tr.length; j++) {
            var valueArray = [];
            var td = li[i].getElementsByTagName("tr")[j].querySelectorAll("td:not(:first-child):not([style*='display:none'])");

            for(var k = 0; k < td.length; k++) {
                td[k].classList.add("class1", "class2");
            }
        }
    }
```

My code works and I get the result which I expect, but I get an error message in firebug: `"TypeError: li[i].getElementsByTagName(...)[j] is undefined"`. Any Idea why my code works even with error message?

And I am not sure if querySelectorAll is the right choice or if some getElement... function is better.

Thanks for help!

Comment: The error occurs because `li[1].getElementsByTagName("tr")` consists of only 3 nodes, and when j is 3 you are trying to access the fourth element which is undefined. Keep in mind that `tr` has a length of 9.

Comment: Oh you're absolutely right. Forgot that when I coded it from jQuery to Javascript. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

may be something like this ?

```js
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('.test ul li tbody td');
tds.forEach(td => td.classList.add('class1','class2'));
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
                <tr><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </li>
        <li>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
                <tr><td>9</td><td>10</td></tr>
                <tr><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </li>
        <li>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr><td>13</td><td>14</td></tr>
                <tr><td>15</td><td>16</td></tr>
                <tr><td>17</td><td>18</td></tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: forEach is for array, and document.querySelectorAll return a NodeList, you can't apply forEach in a NodeList

Comment: isn't working for me, in code snippet console say "message": "Uncaught TypeError: tds.forEach is not a function"